# Windows 11, File explorer sound preview

Tags: windows

Is there a way to preview .wav file with File Explorer, without opening the full Media Player application.

The goal is to quickly go through a bunch of .wav files sample

In previous version of Window it was like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using VLC as default player seems to do the trick,
Tried this https://www.elevenforum.com/t/open-item-with-single-click-or-double-click-in-windows-11.6122/ for the one click access, but it changed the settings for everything.
I just would like this behaviour for the .wav files.